# Search google in WinRT app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, html-parsing

I am trying to add a google search functionality to my WinRT app. I have to do this without the use of the google api. I retrieve the google search page but it is a jungle of html tags. How can i parse this search page to get each search results separately?

```
string url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + txtSearchKey.Text.Trim();
                System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
               System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync(url);
               txtResult.Text = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing it with the HTMLAgility Pack which you can get from nuget or from [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)